# HTML rowspan 1,5 (one and a half)

Tags: html, css, html-table

Let assume I have following table:

```
<table border="2">
<tr>
            <td>abcsss</td>
            <td>sdf</td>
            <td>def</td>
            <td>def</td>
            <td rowspan="1,5">defsssss</td>
</tr>
        <tr>
            <td>abcsss</td>
            <td>sdf</td>
            <td>def</td>
            <td>def</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
            <td>abcsss</td>
            <td>sdf</td>
            <td>def</td>
            <td>def</td>
            <td rowspan="1,5">defsssss</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I know that code rowspan="1,5" isn't working but how would I make it work? Is there some css or html trick to make field like there were rowspan="1,5" working?

Comment: multiply rows and get the effect, what you need. And rowspan=1,5... this is similar to delirium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<tr>
            <td rowspan="2">abcsss</td>
            <td rowspan="2">sdf</td>
            <td rowspan="2">def</td>
            <td rowspan="2">def</td>
            <td rowspan="3">defsssss</td>
</tr>
```

```html
<table border="2">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">abcsss</td>
    <td rowspan="2">sdf</td>
    <td rowspan="2">def</td>
    <td rowspan="2">def</td>
    <td rowspan="3">defsssss</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">abcsss</td>
    <td rowspan="2">sdf</td>
    <td rowspan="2">def</td>
    <td rowspan="2">def</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">defsssss</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">abcsss</td>
    <td rowspan="2">sdf</td>
    <td rowspan="2">def</td>
    <td rowspan="2">def</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What kind of an answer is this? How did you got 88k with answers like this :D BTW can you show an example of this working?

Comment: @BojanPetkovski Do you have an actual objection to my answer? It's pretty simple math.

Comment: Not to the answer itself, but to the way it is answered. I think that just adding some piece of code without explaining how it would help or what it does is not a proper answer and BTW your code snippet is different from the first answer, so do you believe that OP would have done the same snippet from your first answer? No hard feelings, just thinking out loud :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski I'm not generally of the opinion that SO is a "spoon feed people completed code" sort of place.

Answer (score 0):

After 5 years thinking about this problem, finally I found a solution:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Layout Tabla</title>
    <style>
        /*Estilo probado para IE edge, Chrome, FF y Safari*/
        table {
            width: 500px;
        }

        th,
        td {
            border: 2px solid black;
            height: 24px !important;
            text-align: center;
        }

        /*Reseteo de padding, margin y border para celda rowspan = 3*/
        td#celdarowspan3 {
            border: none;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        /*Capa contenedora para celda rowspan = 3*/
        div#contenedora-celdarowspan3 {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        /*1a subfila de celda rowspan = 3*/
        /*Utilizamos propiedad display: flex para alineación de texto centrado con justificación también centrado*/
        /*Añadimos margin-bottom: 2px para establecer separación entre las 2 subfilas*/
        div#subfila1 {
            border: 2px solid black;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
            height: 43%;
            /*display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;*/
            text-align: center;
        }

        /*2a subfila de celda rowspan = 3*/
        /*Utilizamos propiedad display: flex para alineación de texto centrado con justificación también centrado*/
        div#subfila2 {
            border: 2px solid black;
            height: 44%;
            /*display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;*/
            text-align: center;
        }

        /*Media query de css3 para que los estilos sólo se apliquen a Mozilla*/
        /*Puede comentarse puesto que estas propiedades par IE y Chrome no afectan*/
        /*y sólo son necesarias para Mozilla Firefox*/
        /*Permiten que en FF la capa contenedora-celdarowspan3 ocupe todo el alto/ancho*/
        /* de la celda rowspan = 3*/
        /*@-moz-document url-prefix() {*/
        td#celdarowspan3 {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        div#contenedora-celdarowspan3 {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        /* }*/
    </style>
    <script src="chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/prompt.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <caption>Layout Tabla</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="3">Día</th>
                <th colspan="3">Seminario</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Horario</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Tema</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Inicio</th>
                <th>Fin</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Lunes</td>
                <td rowspan="2">8:00</td>
                <td rowspan="2">17:00</td>
                <td>Introducción a XML</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Validación: DTD y Relax NG</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">Martes</td>
                <td>8:00</td>
                <td>11:00</td>
                <td id="celdarowspan3" rowspan="3">
                    <div id="contenedora-celdarowspan3">
                        <div id="subfila1">XPATH</div>
                        <div id="subfila2">Transformaciones XSL</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11:00</td>
                <td>14:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>14:00</td>
                <td>17:00</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Miércoles</td>
                <td>8:00</td>
                <td>12:00</td>
                <td>Formateo de objetos XSL</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are putting 1,5 as a value. Html will only accept integer values